# Sitecore deleting a file from the server with Schedule Tasks

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

In the schedule tasks in Sitecore I want to delete an XML file after data import. Data import is successful but when deleting I get the access denied exception.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'X:\..\Website\temp\import\data.xml' is denied. at 
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost) at Website.Intranet.Kernel.ScheduledTasks.Scheduler.ImportData()
```

This is the code I am using to delete the file.

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Delete(filePath);

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure the user running your application has the rights to delete a file on that location?

Comment: Are you sure you are releasing your file handle after the import is complete?

Comment: Does this error is thrown while running scheduled task? Or you try to debug it while running it somehow else and throw error? Try to wrap your code with using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler()){}

Comment: @Anton I was used security disabler but did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you grant the correct permissions on your target folder for the **Application Pool** identity user on which your website is running. By default the identity is `Application Pool Identity` or `NetworkService`.

Also make sure the containing folder is not **readonly**

Comment: But Sitecore put this file to that location under same identity?